# Bathroom Grout Cracking

Tags: bathroom, grout, caulking, crack, silicone

The bathroom was renovated by the previous owner last year and has been seldom used. However, there are cracks found at the joints, e.g. along the red lines.

- What might be the cause? Was it wrong to apply grout along joints?
- Shall I remove the grout the reseal the joints with silicone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always recommended to caulk different wall planes at their joints and between tiles and the tub. That's where most of the settling will occur and grout will not adjust or expand.  Start out by getting a grout saw and remove all the grout between those surfaces you've marked in red. Wear a mask. Remove all the residue. Then get a quality silicone caulk and caulk the wall seams and the bottom tile row to the tub. Use a thick bead of caulk, 1/4" works well. Caulk slowly for deeper penetration of the caulk.

Comment: +1- this is the correct answer- I used to use silicon but haven't for years now. It seems to always grow mildew and get ugly within a few years. Most tile grout companies make caulking, sold in caulk gun cartridge tubes, that matches whatever grout color you have chosen. It is available in sanded or unsanded to match your grout. This is a modified latex caulk which is much easier to apply and looks 100% better than silicon.

Comment: Note: Fill the bath with water when you caulk round it. It makes the caulk line the widest it will ever be in use [so long as the building isn't moving] & save strain on the joint.

Comment: Is it okay to have some grout left inside before caulking? I'm acutually don't know how deep I should go to avoid the water barrier in the wall. Thank you.

Comment: You should have at least 1/4 to 3/8" depth free of grout.

Comment: Some part of the gap is as narrow as a snap blade, thus it's very difficult to remove the grout inside. Any idea on this issue? Thank you.